# Service Auth issues with uploading data onto google fusion tables

Tags: android, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

So, I'm having some issues with the service Auth function in MIT's App Inventor. I'm getting a `400 bad request: { "error": "invalid_grant" }` every time I attempt to upload to the fusion table.

I've tried setting up a new service auth account as well, under a new project (which worked the last time when I had a 404 issue). 
However, google isn't giving me a `XXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com` to use, but is instead generating a `account-#@bla-1129.iam.gserviceaccount.com` email address, which bounces when you invite it to edit your fusion table.

SOS. I'm floundering out here.

Comment: see my detailed setup instructions here https://puravidaapps.com/fusionservice.php

Comment: Hey Mr. Taifun,

Part of the ongoing problem is that Google Developers Console is not giving me an email that can be invited to join the google doc I've created. For example, when you share the document with the new email address generated by the service auth credential, you get an email message like the following:

"Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     account-4@bla-1129.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
DNS Error: Address resolution of bla-1129.iam.gserviceaccount.com. failed: Domain name not found"

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it does not make much sense, to notify a service account by email...

Share the FusionTable with the ServiceAccount Email address , set the permissions to "can edit" and **disable the checkbox "Notify people by email"**.

[image]

**See also my updated description of all steps here: https://puravidaapps.com/fusionservice.php**