# How do I fix a 403 error using OAuth in App Inventor 2?

Tags: android, oauth, app-inventor

So I switched from using the Service Auth email service to using a OAuth for the app I'm designing in order to communicate with my fusion table. Here's the issue: I'm now getting the following: "403 Forbidden Access Not Configured. The API (Fusion Tables API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."

The funny part? I've enabled that API. Heck, I enabled, disabled, and re-enabled it.

What should I be looking for? What do I need to change in order to "enable" my enabled Fusion Tables API?

Thanks in advance, and I'll keep fiddling with it on my end.
/Zach

Answer (score 0):

For the built in fusiontable controls there are only 2 possibilities

1. to use the API key method, see the [Pizza Party tutorial](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/pizzaparty) how to set this up, or
2. to use the service account method, [see here for setup instructions](https://puravidaapps.com/fusionservice.php)

It is recommended to use the service account method, because for several Android versions you will get an [error 401 Invalid Credentials](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/invalid$20credentials) for the API key method...

**For support on errors, see also [puravidaapps.com/fusionerror.php](https://puravidaapps.com/fusionerror.php)**

Comment: Hey Taifun,

I can understand that. However, the service auth route continuously gave me the same 401 error, no matter what I tried. I've since incorporated what you had written on your OAuth tutorial, and have made it to a point where I get the 403 error. 

I did a little digging online, and found that other users had the same issue, and resolved it by enabling both the Google + API, and the Contacts API. I've done both. The fusion tables API is active. So the real question is why is the app telling me that it's inactive on the user's end?

Comment: what OAuth tutorial are you talking about? [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33743657/1545993) to your other question and follow my [detailed instructions about the setup here](https://puravidaapps.com/fusionservice.php)

Comment: Hey Taifun, This is the tutorial I used for setting up the OAuth, and I followed the instructions on setting up the service account, but the service account route continued to bounce back with a 401 "invalid credentials" error no matter what I did (including redoing all the blocks in the section).

So I'm trying with the OAuth function. I just need to figure out why the Developers Console won't recognize that I have the Fusion Tables API enabled.

Comment: Are you using an emulator for your tests? You might want to continue with the service account method and in case there are still issues, [edit your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33709209/1545993) and provide some more information. As already mentioned, the API key method is not the way to go...

Comment: Hey Taifun, no, I'm actually running it live on my tablet (I ran into emulator problems when I was first getting started, and a comment you made on someone else's post helped gear me towards just doing things this way. Longer to do, but more accurate.). I'd also like to resrict access to the Fusion Table as well, so I figure it might be best to use your O Auth approach, too!

Comment: One thing that is different in my app from your O Auth demonstration online is that my app is not calling forth the google login screen. I'm thinking there might be some step here that I'm missing.

Comment: ??? what are you talking about? For the service account method there never will show up a Google Login screen... Btw. Stackoverflow is not really a site for discussions, so if you have a question, then start a question and someone else can provide an answer. Thank you. See also [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hey Taifun, so I'm not trying to start a discussion but I am clarifying what's going on with my app. Right now, I tried using the service auth method and it (a) did not work even after following your detailed instructions, and (b) does not work for the particular functionality I'd like to have with this app. So, the question is simply as follows: what do I need to edit in my developers console so that the O Auth will work without giving me a 403 error that says the Fusion Tables API is not enabled. If the API is not recognized, even your service auth method will not work.

Comment: The answer is also simple: use the service account method and follow the instructions EXACTLY  https://puravidaapps.com/fusionservice.php For support on errors, see also https://puravidaapps.com/fusionerror.php

Comment: Okay. I'll look into it.

Comment: Hey Taifun, I followed your instructions exactly and I'm still receiving the following--400: "error": "invalid_grant".